# How do I split a list with .xml attributes and concatenate the information into a string array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, list

I'm able to display the data in the .xml, but I want the four tags' information: group, leader, emal, and month to become elements in a string array and I don't want to display the name of the tags in that array. Update: As suggested, I can use LINQ for the solution.

```
private static List<string> groupLeaderList;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"E:\team_groups.xml");
        groupLeaderList = new List<string>();
        XmlDocument XMLfile = new XmlDocument();            
        XmlNode groupLeadersNode = XMLfile.SelectSingleNode("/team_groups/team/group");

        do
        {
            groupLeaderList.Add(file.ReadLine());
        }
        while (groupLeaderList.Last() != null);
        file.Close();

        foreach (string s in groupLeaderList)
        {
            //String[] groupSplit = groupLeaderList.???
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

sample data used in .xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <team_groups>
- <team>

  <group>Mushroom Kingdom</group> 
  <leader>Mario Bros</leader> 
  <email>Mario@nintendo.com</email> 
  <month>1</month> 

  <group>Donut Plains</group> 
  <leader>Mario Bros</leader> 
  <email>Mario@Nintendo.com</email> 
  <month>2</month> 
  </team>

- <team>
  <group>Midgard Kingdom</group> 
  <leader>King Tristan Gaebolg</leader> 
  <email>king.t@midgard.com</email> 
  <month>1</month> 
  </team>
  </team_groups>


I want to output: Mushroom Kingdom, Mario Bros, Mario@nintendo.com, 1
Donut Plains, Mario Bros, Mario@nintendo.com, 2
Midgard Kingdom, King Tristan Gaebolg, king.t@midgard.com, 1
```

Comment: Your first team has two of each of the elemnts group, leader, email, month. Was that intentional?

Comment: @ConradFrix Yes, I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach this. In reality. each leader has multiple teams, let me update it since the leader Bowser makes it confusing.

Comment: Do you control the XML file?  Because while possible to read this, it's not ideal - other than the order there's nothing to imply that those 4 elements are grouped together.

Comment: Yes, I can modify the .xml. I'm trying to run a function with leaders that are responsible for something at a certain month using a timestamp, so I was only going to read every single line and check the value of the 4th array to see if the user is responsible the 1st , 2nd, etc, month. I can already do this but I did it with a .txt file and I need to do it from a .xml as long as the leader has the month that meets the timestamp, I will use the rest of the array information on my function.

Comment: Why not group the 4 elements with another element then?  For example, a `leader` element that contains `name`, `group`, `email`, `month`.  Having to rely on counting every 4th element is likely to come back to bite you.

Comment: @CharlesMagerm yes. it's already bitting back. This was a very inneficient XML format I followed =-s

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an `XmlDocument`, you don't load any data into it, you try to select some nodes, and then do nothing with those either - so you're basically just reading an XML file with a `StreamReader` - this is why you're getting every line as it appears in the XML file, including the tags.

I'd suggest you look at LINQ to XML to read this, for example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"path\to\file\team_groups.xml");

foreach (var team in doc.Descendants("team"))
{
    var group = (string)team.Element("group");
    var leader = (string)team.Element("leader");
    var email = (string)team.Element("email");
    var month = (int)team.Element("month");

    // do something with these
}
```

Comment: This would drop the second set of nodes in the first tream

Comment: It says I cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable when I declare, var doc = testing.load(@"path"\myxml.xml);

Comment: That's not the same as the code in the answer.  What is `testing`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a temporal variable I created because I didn't know about XDocument until today. I tested your code properly and It works. Do I create an additinal label since I wanted to use the first 4 elements before moving on

Answer (score 1):

With an XDocument object, you can give this a try.  It stores everything in a `List<string>`.  Once you have everything in your `List`, you can pull 4 elements at a time and create a Team class object and use those objects as you see fit.

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>" +
                "<team_groups>" +
                "<team>" +
                "<group>Mushroom Kingdom</group>" +
                "<leader>Mario Bros</leader>" +
                "<email>Mario@nintendo.com</email>" +
                "<month>1</month>" +
                "<group>Donut Plains</group>" +
                "<leader>Mario Bros</leader>" +
                "<email>Mario@Nintendo.com</email>" +
                "<month>2</month>" +
                "</team>" +
                "<team>" +
                "<group>Midgard Kingdom</group>" +
                "<leader>King Tristan Gaebolg</leader>" +
                "<email>king.t@midgard.com</email>" +
                "<month>1</month>" +
                "</team>" +
                "</team_groups>";

XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
List<string> elements = xDocument.Descendants("team").SelectMany(team => 
    team.Descendants().Select(element => element.Value)).ToList();

List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i += 4)
{
    teams.Add(new Team {
        Group = elements[i],
        Leader = elements[i + 1],
        Email = elements[i + 2],
        Month = elements[i + 3],
    });   
}
teams.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Team Class:

```
public class Team
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Leader { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}\r\n{3}\r\n", Group, Leader, Email, Month);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Mushroom Kingdom
Mario Bros
Mario@nintendo.com
1

Donut Plains
Mario Bros
Mario@Nintendo.com
2

Midgard Kingdom
King Tristan Gaebolg
king.t@midgard.com
1
```

Comment: Why not use `var element = xDocument.Descendants("team").SelectMany(team => 
    team.Descendants().Select(element => element.Value)).ToList();` instead?

Comment: Wow. I think I'll run into trouble because I was trying to tell my program that, Mushroom Kingdom, Mario Bros, Mario@nintendo.com, 1 are information that must be used together. How will my program know when a group ends and starts?

Comment: @juharr That works too!  Didn't think of that.  Nice!

Comment: @Pokarface What do you mean "are information that must be used together"?  Every 4 elements in the list make up your group, so use them accordingly.

Comment: @juharr ok! I wanted to use all the 4 elements in a group before moving on to the next group and I got scarred when I saw the list in descending order with all the groups. So I can create a group with 4 elements, do something with it, and then create a new group with its elements and do something else, right?

Comment: @Pokarface Personally I'd create a team class and do something like `var teams = xDocument.Descendants("team").Select(team => [create your Team object here]);`

Comment: @Pokarface Yes, once you have your list grab 4 elements at a time and do something with them before going on to the next 4 elements.

Comment: @Pokarface See updated answer for using 4 elements in a group